# SQL Server : changing dot to comma during export

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv

When I try to export data from SQL Server to a `.csv` file, it will change values from `1.00` to `1,00` and therefore the delimiter which is also broken.

Is there some way around this so it will actually use the dot?

Comment: Use a Quote Identifier or use a different delimiter. A CSV doesn't *have* to be Comma Separated.

Comment: How do you export data to a CSV file? The data import/export wizard in Management Studio? Some T-SQL script? Excel? `sqlcmd`? SQL Server does not change numeric values so much as that they have to somehow be represented as strings before they go into a file -- how that happens is up to the client code processing the data. You can control the way this happens explicitly using the `FORMAT` function, but that requires modifying the query of whatever is doing the export.

Comment: I'm using the SQL Import and Export Wizard.

Comment: I don't have full access to where I get the data from, but can i use the format thing when I specify what query to use when exporting the data? @JeroenMostert

Comment: Might be a language setting (at a guess), but I *doubt* that the import/export wizard would do something so *"foolish"* as to use a comma (`,`) instead of a period (`.`) for a decimal place when exporting to a CSV. I feel like this would have been something that was complained about many years ago and fixed or documented as a "feature". Which suggests that the SQL returning the data is transforming the value before the CSV export, like @JeroenMostert surmises.

Comment: If you're using the import/export wizard to export to a flat file destination, you should be able to use the "locale" setting to specify what number and date formatting to use. E.g. pick "English (United States)" to get numbers with a period for the separator (disclaimer: not tested). You can also choose "write a query" instead of copying from a table, which allows you to explicitly use `FORMAT` in a `SELECT`, but that's more work. Make sure to check it's actually the CSV containing the "wrong" format and not whatever you're using to open it; Excel has a habit of that, for example.

Comment: I try to change language settings and other stuff in the Wizard but it stays the same. I've tried to open in Excel, Notepad and Notepad++. How can I setup my query with format? My original query looks something like this:

`select * from dbo.ShipmentInfo where date = '2019-01-30'`

Comment: You'll have to break down `dbo.ShipmentInfo` to identify the columns you want (and what they contain). `SELECT FORMAT(NumberColumn, 'g', 'en-US') AS NumberColumn FROM ...` [See also](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql).

Comment: There is a lot of columns, and two of them is using decimals. Is it not possible to get all columns and tell it to use the correct format when needed?

Comment: You already have all the columns in your exported file (first line) so modifying that into a column list should not be hard. But other than that, no, you can't tell SQL Server to cough up all numeric columns as strings in a particular format -- that's usually the job of the client. SQL Server sends over the values as-is, in a binary format, with no separator whatsoever. You could consider using other tools, like `bcp`, to see if those will cooperate better ([example](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/creating-csv-files-using-bcp-and-stored-procedures/)).

Comment: Thank you! That worked :) 

`SELECT ID, FORMAT(Weight, 'g', 'en-US') as Weight, FORMAT(Volume, 'g', 'en-US') as Volume, LotsOfOtherColumns FROM dbo.ShipmentInfo where date = '2019-01-30'`